# Remove the number of the post of the url

Tags: .htaccess, url

I have a folder where I will save all the posts from a blog. It will be useful for me to have each file with a number. This way I can have things organized and easy to find. But the user does not need that number and it would be better to have a cleaner URL without it.

I am familiar with `RewriteEngine` rules in the `htaccess`. But I do not know how to do it in this case.

For example: I would like to have in my local folder and in the server:

```
www.example.com/blog/4-theTitleOfthe4post  
www.example.com/blog/5-theTitleOfthe5post
```

and so on…

I would like the user to have something like:

```
www.example.com/blog/theTitleOfthe4post  
www.example.com/blog/theTitleOfthe5post
```

and so on…

Is it possible to have a clean url without the number of the post? and still have the files organized internally and in the server with the number of the post?

Comment: If user sends `/theTitleOfthe4post` in URI then how are you planning to translate this into correct filename?

Comment: That is the point. With the conventional use of cleaning URL it is not possible. That is why I am asking is there is any other way

Comment: URL rewriting can not magically make up necessary info, that you removed deliberately. You would need some sort of script that reads the whole directory content, and checks if there is any `x-foobar` file that matches your requested URL segment of just `foobar`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

```
RewriteRule ^(blog/)(\D*(\d+)\D*)$ /$1$3-$2
```

https://regexr.com/4kjth

Comment: I do not understand. Please explain.

Comment: Are you sure that this can have the url without the number of the post? Explain how

Comment: @Nrc Can you be more specific about what part is confusing? It finds a number in the URL, copies it to the front, and adds a dash.

Comment: I think your regex does not work. I tested here. https://regexr.com/4kjms But that is not important.

Comment: If I put a code in the .htaccess to redirect from the url with the number to the url without the number, what will be visible is the url with the number.

Comment: how will that help to clean the url?